# Azure cloud full operational management without ownership

Tags: azure, cloud

Azure allows partners to manage customer's resources.
But as startups serving enterprise customers, we might be asked to install our software on customer's Azure Linux server resource and manage it, but we dont want them to access the Linux box via shell or clone it entirely thereby making a copy without our knowledge. How do you solve this?

Comment: I do not understand clearly. The Azure Linux Server belongs to the customer, you're the partner and you want to restrict the customer's permission?

Comment: Yes. effectively. It might "belong" to customer, but we want to block all access to that, and possibility of cloning the entire instance, assuming the customer willingly gives this sort of permission, once acquiring the box. Think of it as you buy a car, but manufacturer do not want you to disassemble the engine, without some sort of advance notification or permission process involving the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a web application that would talk to the OS and perform the administrative tasks you wish. This way, you only need to open one port (possiblity 443 - HTTPS) and share login credentials w/ your partner. This way your OS is protected -- administrative tasks can only be performed through a web UI.

By doing a quick Google search, you can find some open-source options:

- http://ajenti.org/
- http://www.webmin.com/
- https://cockpit-project.org/

You need to ensure you create users for your customer with limited access. Get Webdmin as an example: https://doxfer.webmin.com/Webmin/Webmin_Users

> A standard, out-of-the-box Webmin installation has only one user
>   (called root or admin) who can use every feature of every module. On a
>   home or office system used by just one person, that is all you need.
>   Even if your system has multiple users, there may be only one who
>   needed to perform system administration tasks.
>
> However, there are many situations in which the administrator may want
>   to give some people access to a subset of Webmin's features. For
>   example, you may have a person in your organization whose job it is to
>   create and edit DNS zones and records. On a normal Unix system, this
>   person would have to be given root access so that he can edit the zone
>   files and re-start the DNS server when necessary. Unfortunately, once
>   someone is able to login as root he has full control of the system and
>   can do whatever he wants.
>
> Webmin solves this kind of problem by allowing you to create
>   additional users who can login, but only access a few modules. **You can
>   further restrict what the user can do within each module, so that he
>   cannot abuse its features to perform actions that he is not supposed
>   to**. Because Webmin still runs with full root privileges even when used
>   by a restricted user, it still has access to all the configuration
>   files and commands that it needs.

Answer (score 0):

For the install, I'd write a bash script to install your application by wget'ing the binaries and setting some environment settings. If you want to take it a step further, your client can create an ARM template that spins up the VM and installs your app via [custom script extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machine-scale-sets/tutorial-install-apps-powershell#create-custom-script-extension-definition). When it comes to managing the application, you should be able to view log files in Azure using [Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net-trace-logs) and perform administrative functions using the app. If an issue arises that cannot be diagnosed from the log files and the built-in app diagnostics (e.g. the install failed, app cannot write to log files in local dir), I'd do a screen share with the client and troubleshoot.